# Sync error on a Grails project in IntelliJ

Tags: grails, maven, intellij-idea

All of a sudden I get this error in IntelliJ, the project runs outside the IDE fine. I can create and run new projects fine too.

```
IDEA hook: Grails not found!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.grails.rt.Agent$2.run(Agent.java:99)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

This error is precedded by some suspicious lines:

```
[INFO]    task-segment: [grails:exec] (aggregator-style)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [grails:exec {execution: default-cli}]
[FATAL ERROR] org.grails.maven.plugin.GrailsExecMojo#execute() caused a linkage error (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError) and may be out-of-date. Check the realms:
[FATAL ERROR] Plugin realm = app0.child-container[org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:1.3.7]
```

Comment: What is the IDEA version and the Grails version?

Comment: Sergey, I've been runnning Grails 1.3.7 on IDEA 11.1.3 for a while now without issues. Today I tried to install a plugin that was meant to run on Grails 2.0+ The install failed and rolled back the plugin but IDEA never recovered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgraded to 11.1.4 latest RC and this resolved the issue.

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+11.1+EAP

Comment: true, that was awhile ago, I just added the answer for completeness and accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue as well.  After trying various methods, I resulted to deleting my .iml project file and completely reimporting the maven project.

This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked, in the context menu on intellij, right-click the module, then select: Grails > Synchronize Grails Settings. And try again